Error: "Database Does Not Exist" when executing CREATE DATABASE and USE statements in SQL Server
I get an error "Database does not exist" when executing CREATE DATABASE and USE statements at the same time.
This is the SQL Server version I'm using:
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)   Oct  8 2022 05:58:25   
Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045)

When I click execute button in SSMS to run script with commands like below:
CREATE DATABASE SalesManagement;
USE SalesManagement; 

In the result tag there is a message:

Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Database 'SalesManagement' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

hy does this error appear? And how to fix it?
Thanks!

you can't use a database in the same batch as where you create it. Try:
CREATE DATABASE X <newline> GO <newline> USE X Replace  with actual new line :) GO is a batch separator in SSMS

Please patch your instance - there have been 14 cumulative updates since RTM and they publish those for very good reasons.

You Need to use GO in between 2 statements.
Creating a Database and using a database cannot be done on the same batch. So we need to use batch separator "GO" to separate creation and using.
CREATE DATABASE SalesManagement;
GO
USE SalesManagement; 

